# Logic Apps managed identity deployed with DevOps bicep template gets error sending to Service Bus topic

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azureservicebus, azure-managed-identity, azure-bicep

I'm creating a logic app with managed identity to send a message to service bus using bicep.

My main.bicep runs four modules in sequence (using DependsOn) to do the following.

- Set up Service Bus with system-assigned identity and creating the
  target topic.
- Create the API connection to the namespace endpoint
- Create the Logic App with system assigned identity and referencing the Service Bus API
  connection, specifying the authentication as managed identity.
- Assigning Service Bus Sender RBAC role to the topic.

Everything looks right when I view the deployment in the portal. However, I am encountering a 401 error in trying to send a message to the topic from the Logic App I have granted access to.

"status": 401,
"message": "40100: Unauthorized : Unauthorized access for 'Send' operation on endpoint 'sb://[sb-name-redacted].servicebus.windows.net/[topic-name-redacted]'

Manually creating an API connection post-deployment via the logic app designer results in successful message delivery so I'm obviously doing something wrong.

It’s driving me absolutely crazy not being able to figure out where the issue is.

Below is the code from the modules being run. Can anyone help??

Service Bus module

```
//service bus
resource resource_servicebus 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces@2022-01-01-preview' = {
  name: servicebus
  location: location
  sku: {
    [removed for brevity]
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    [removed for brevity]
  }
}


//topics
resource resource_topic_recurlywebhook 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics@2022-01-01-preview' = {
  parent: resource_servicebus
  name: topic_[redacted]
  location: location
  properties: {
    [removed for brevity]
  }
}
```

API Connections module

```
resource resource_connections_servicebus 'Microsoft.Web/connections@2018-07-01-preview' = {
  name: connections_servicebus
  location: location
  kind: 'V1'
  properties: {
    api: {
      id: connections_id_servicebus
    }
    displayName: connections_servicebus
    parameterValueSet: {
      name: 'managedIdentityAuth'
      values: {
        namespaceEndpoint:{
          value: 'sb://${servicebus}.servicebus.windows.net'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Logic Apps module

```
//api connections

resource resource_connections_servicebus 'Microsoft.Web/connections@2018-07-01-preview' existing = {
  name: connections_servicebus
}


//logic apps
resource resource_lapp_ae_[redacted] 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows@2019-05-01' = {
  name: lapp_ae_[redacted]
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    state: 'Enabled'
    definition: {
      '$schema': 'https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#'
      contentVersion: '1.0.0.0'
      parameters: {
        '$connections': {
          defaultValue: {
          }
          type: 'Object'
        }
      }
      triggers: [removed for brevity]
      actions: {
        Response_200: [removed for brevity]
        Response_500: [removed for brevity]
        Send_message_to_[redacted]_topic: {
          runAfter: {
          }
          type: 'ApiConnection'
          inputs: {
            body: {
              ContentData: '@{base64(triggerBody())}'
              CorrelationId: '@{guid()}'
              Properties: '@triggerBody()'
            }
            host: {
              connection: {
                name: '@parameters(\'$connections\')[\'servicebus\'][\'connectionId\']'
              }
            }
            method: 'post'
            path: '/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(\'[redacted]\'))}/messages'
          }
        }
      }
      outputs: {
      }
    }
    parameters: {
      '$connections': {
        value: {
          servicebus: {
            connectionId: resource_connections_servicebus.id
            connectionName: resource_connections_servicebus.name
            connectionProperties: {
              authentication: {
                type: 'ManagedServiceIdentity'
              }
            }
            id: connections_id_servicebus
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

///////////////////////////////// outputs ///////////////////////////////////////////////

output principalid_lapp_ae_rc_to_sb_connector string = resource_lapp_ae_rc_to_sb_connector.identity.principalId
```

Service Bus Role Assignment module

```
//define roles to assign
var rbac_service_bus_data_sender = '69a216fc-b8fb-44d8-bc22-1f3c2cd27a39'


//define apps to send to topics
param topic_[redacted]_access_list array = [
  principalid_lapp_ae_[redacted]
]

//////////////////////////// call resources to grant access to ////////////////////////////////

resource resource_servicebus 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces@2022-01-01-preview' existing = {
   name: servicebus
}



resource resource_topic_[redacted] 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics@2022-01-01-preview' existing = {
  parent: resource_servicebus
  name: topic_[redacted]
}


//////////////////////////// make role assignments ////////////////////////////////

resource resource_topic_[redacted]_access_list 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01'  = [for principalID in topic_[redacted]_access_list: {
  scope: resource_topic_[redacted]
  name: guid(resource_topic_[redacted].id, principalID, rbac_service_bus_data_sender)
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', rbac_service_bus_data_sender)
    principalId: principalID
    principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
  }
}]
```

Comment: I suggest raising a case with Microsoft on this one.

Comment: Thanks Skin - will do that.

Comment: What is the value of `connections_id_servicebus` ? should be something like that: `id: '/subscriptions/${subscription().subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/${location}/managedApis/servicebus'`

Comment: It is 

```param connections_id_servicebus string = '/subscriptions/${subscription_id}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/${location}/managedApis/servicebus'```

where subscription id is

```param subscription_id string= subscription().subscriptionId```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a managed identity for servicebus connector as describe in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/servicebus/#managed-identity-authentication)

Here I am deploying:

- a servicebus namespace, one topic and one subscription
- a user assigned identity with `Azure Service Bus Data Sender` role at the servicebus level.
- a servicebus connector for logic app
- a simple logic app:
  [image]

I have a module for servicebus role assignment:

```
// servicebus-role-assignment.bicep

param serviceBusName string
param principalId string
param principalType string = 'ServicePrincipal'
param roleId string

resource serviceBus 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces@2022-10-01-preview' existing = {
  name: serviceBusName
}

resource roleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
  name: guid(serviceBus.id, roleId, principalId)
  scope: serviceBus
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', roleId)
    principalId: principalId
    principalType: principalType
  }
}
```

And a main deployment file (added some default values for simplicity):

```
// main.bicep

param location string = resourceGroup().location
param servicebusName string = 'logicappthomastestsb'
param servicebusconnectorName string = 'servicebus-connector'
param topicName string = 'thomastest-topic'
param topicsubName string = 'thomastest-subscription'
param identityName string = 'logicapp-thomastest-mi'
param logicAppName string = 'logicapp-thomastest'

// Create service bus
resource serviceBus 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces@2022-10-01-preview' = {
  name: servicebusName
  location: location
  tags: resourceGroup().tags
  properties: {
    zoneRedundant: false
    minimumTlsVersion: '1.2'
    disableLocalAuth: true
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
  }
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard'
    tier: 'Standard'
  }
}

// Create topic
resource topic 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics@2022-10-01-preview' = {
  parent: serviceBus
  name: topicName
}

// Create subscription
resource subscription 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/subscriptions@2022-10-01-preview' = {
  parent: topic
  name: topicsubName
}

// Create managed identity
resource identity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2023-01-31' = {
  name: identityName
  location: location
}

// Assign role to managed identity
module roleAssignment 'servicebus-role-assignment.bicep' = {
  name: 'servicebus-logicapp-rbac'
  scope: resourceGroup()
  params: {
    serviceBusName: serviceBus.name
    principalId: identity.properties.principalId
    roleId: '69a216fc-b8fb-44d8-bc22-1f3c2cd27a39' // Azure Service Bus Data Sender
  }
}

// Create servicebus connection api
resource connectionApi 'Microsoft.Web/connections@2016-06-01' = {
  name: servicebusconnectorName
  location: location
  kind: 'V1'
  properties: {
    api: {
      id: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis', location, 'servicebus')
    }
    parameterValueSet: {
      name: 'managedIdentityAuth'
      values: {
        namespaceEndpoint: {
          value: 'sb://${serviceBus.name}.servicebus.windows.net/'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

resource logicApp 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows@2019-05-01' = {
  name: logicAppName
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${identity.id}': {}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    state: 'Enabled'
    definition: {
      '$schema': 'https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#'
      contentVersion: '1.0.0.0'
      parameters: {
        '$connections': {
          defaultValue: {}
          type: 'Object'
        }
        topicName: {
          defaultValue: ''
          type: 'String'
        }
      }
      triggers: {
        When_a_HTTP_request_is_received: {
          inputs: {}
          kind: 'Http'
          type: 'Request'
        }
      }
      actions: {
        Send_message: {
          inputs: {
            body: {
              ContentData: '@{base64(\'Hello from logic app\')}'
            }
            host: {
              connection: {
                name: '@parameters(\'$connections\')[\'servicebus\'][\'connectionId\']'
              }
            }
            method: 'post'
            path: '/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(parameters(\'topicName\')))}/messages'
          }
          runAfter: {}
          type: 'ApiConnection'
        }
      }
      outputs: {}
    }
    parameters: {
      '$connections': {
        value: {
          servicebus: {
            connectionId: connectionApi.id
            connectionName: connectionApi.name
            connectionProperties: {
              authentication: {
                type: 'ManagedServiceIdentity'
                identity: identity.id
              }
            }
            id: connectionApi.properties.api.id
          }
        }
      }
      topicName: {
        value: topic.name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using Az CLI to deploy:

```
az deployment group create --resource-group <resource-group-name> --template-file ./main.bicep
```

One the deployment is done:
[image]

I am able to trigger the logic app successfully:
[image]

Run details:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have been informed that managed identity authentication is not currently available for Logic App (Consumption) as I had configured it. It does however work with Logic App (Standard).

Comment: From the documentation, azure servicebus is supported using consumption plan: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-managed-service-identity?tabs=consumption#where-you-can-use-a-managed-identity. I gave it a try and it is working fine. Also saying you made it worked configuring manually so there is no reason it would not work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).